# Jquery concat variable to string doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, concatenation

I got the value of the input element with id mydata into a variable 's' .
When I concatenate this variable to another string , the resulting string doesn't have the variable in it.

```
$("#mydata").change(function () {
   var s =$("#mydata").val();
   var link = "<a href='{%url 'download' "+s+" %}' style='color:darkslategrey;'>View E-Brochure</a>";
});
```

Variable s has value 1 
the resulting string is:

```
<a href="/download/%7B0%7D" style="color:darkslategrey;">View E-Brochure </a>
```

but I'm expecting,

```
  <a href="/download/1" style="color:darkslategrey;">View E-Brochure </a>
```

Comment: Check s value before appending it. you can use console or alert to check the value.

Comment: Have you checked 's' value. Is it '1'?

Answer (score 1):

Your script is missing closing parentheses and a semi-colon.

```
 $("#mydata").change(function () {  
   var s = $("#mydata").val();
   var link = "<a href='{%url 'download' "+s+" %}' style='color:darkslategrey;'>View E-Brochure</a>";
   alert(link);
 });
```

[working link](https://codepen.io/jnakirsten/pen/jOEWjBx)

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to paste it. This is just a part of my script.